# How can I combine two lists of dimensions to a list of points in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have:

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x2 = [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

How can I combine them to points:

```
points = [[1,1],[2,4], ...]
```

Comment: It could be duplicated, but the title of the other questions is not that straightforward. So I didn't find them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> X1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> X2 = [1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> 
>>> [list(pair) for pair in zip(X1, X2)]
>>> [[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16]]
```

If there's no particular reason to have the elements be lists, just use `zip` on its own to produce an iterator (Python 3) or list (Python 2) of tuples.

```
>>> list(zip(X1, X2)) # or just zip(X1, X2) in Python 2
>>> [(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16)]
```

And if you don't even need all of these pairs in memory at the same time, for example if all you want to do is iterate over them, don't build a list. In Python 3, `zip` produces an iterator.

```
>>> pairs = zip(X1, X2)
>>> for pair in pairs:
...:    print(pair)
...:    
(1, 1)
(2, 4)
(3, 9)
(4, 16)
>>> 
>>> pairs = zip(X1, X2)
>>> next(pairs)
>>> (1, 1)
>>> next(pairs)
>>> (2, 4)
```

Finally, if you want the Python 3 `zip` in Python 2, use [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) from `itertools`.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `zip` function:

```
>>> for pair in zip(x1, x2):
...    print(pair)
...
(1, 1)
(2, 4)
(3, 9)
(4, 16)
>>>
```

It yields a sequence of tuples, each containing a value from each of the arguments - in this case, with two arguments, you get two-element tuples.

If you really need lists, use

```
for pair in zip(x1, x2):
    print(list(pair))
```

Also, be careful because if all the arguments aren't exactly the same length `zip` silently drops any values remaining after the shortest argument is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` with `map` for iterating through lists simultaneously:

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x2 = [1, 4, 9, 16]

print(list(map(list, zip(x1, x2))))
# [[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16]]
```

`zip(x1, x2)` returns a tuple of zipped values. We use `map` to convert these tuples to list to match with desired output. Since, `map` in Python 3 generates a map object, we cast it to list again to match with the desired output.

Comment: This seems a little clumsy, and the `map` makes it harder to understand. There are easier ways to produce the needed lists. How about `list([a, b] for (a, b) in zip(x1,x2))` for example.

Comment: @holdenweb, `map` is never harder to understand atleast to me. Moreover, if your list is significantly large, this can perform lazy operation which is handy at times.

Comment: As can the generator expression `([a, b] for (a, b) in zip(x1,x2))` unless I am mistaken. `map` isn't the hammer that turns all Python problems into nails!